# Can I safely access potentially unallocated memory addresses?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, signals

I'm trying to create memcpy like function that will fail gracefully (ie return an error instead of segfaulting) when given an address in memory that is part of an unallocated page. I think the right approach is to install a sigsegv signal handler, and do something in the handler to make the memcpy function stop copying.

But I'm not sure what happens in the case my program is multithreaded:

- Is it possible for the signal handler to execute in another thread?
- What happens if a segfault isn't related to any memcpy operation?
- How does one handle two threads executing memcpy concurrently?
- Am I missing something else? Am I looking for something that's impossible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me, you do *not* want to go down that road. It's a can of worms for many reasons. Correct signal handling is already hard in single threaded environments, yet alone in multithreaded code.

First of all, returning from a signal handler that was caused by an exception condition is undefined behavior - it works in Linux, but it's still undefined behavior nevertheless, and it will give you problems sooner or later.

From `man 2 sigaction`:

> The behaviour of a process is undefined after it returns normally from
>   a signal-catching function for a  SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL or SIGSEGV
>   signal that was not generated by kill(), sigqueue() or raise().

(Note: this does not appear on the Linux manpage; [but it's in SUSv2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigaction.html))

This is also specified in POSIX. While it works in Linux, it's not good practice.

Below the specific answers to your questions:

> Is it possible for the signal handler to execute in another thread?

Yes, it is. A signal is delivered to any thread that is not blocking it (but is delivered only to one, of course), although in Linux and many other UNIX variants, exception-related signals (`SIGILL`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGBUS` and `SIGSEGV`) are usually delivered to the thread that caused the exception. This is not required though, so for maximum portability you shouldn't rely on it.

You can use `pthread_sigmask(2)` to block signals in every thread but one; that way you make sure that every signal is always delivered to the same thread. This makes it easy to have a single thread dedicated to signal handling, which in turn allows you to do synchronous signal handling, because the thread may use `sigwait(2)` (note that multithreaded code should use `sigwait(2)` rather than `sigsuspend(2)`) until a signal is delivered and then handle it synchronously. This is a very common pattern.

> What happens if a segfault isn't related to any memcpy operation?

Good question. The signal is delivered, and there is no (trivial) way to portably differentiate a genuine segfault from a segfault in `memcpy(3)`.

If you have one thread taking care of every signal, like I mentioned above, you could use `sigwaitinfo(2)`, and then examine the `si_addr` field of `siginfo_t` once `sigwaitinfo(2)` returned. The `si_addr` field is the memory location that caused the fault, so you could compare that to the memory addresses passed to `memcpy(3)`.

But some platforms, most notably Mac OS, do not implement `sigwaitinfo(2)` or its cousin `sigtimedwait(2)`.

So there's no way to do it portably.

> How does one handle two threads executing memcpy concurrently?

I don't really understand this question, what's so special about multithreaded `memcpy(3)`? It is the caller's responsibility to make sure regions of memory being read from and written to are not concurrently accessed; `memcpy(3)` isn't (and never was) thread-safe if you pass it overlapping buffers.

> Am I missing something else? Am I looking for something that's
>   impossible to implement?

If you're concerned with portability, I would say it's pretty much impossible. Even if you just focus on Linux, it will be hard. If this was something easy to do, by this time someone would have probably done it already.

I think you're better off building your own allocator and force user code to rely on it. Then you can store state and manage allocated memory, and easily tell if the buffers passed are valid or not.

Comment: Regarding my third bullet, there's nothing special about it, it's just that if two threads are registered somewhere as performing memcpy then I'm not sure how I can tell which thread to attribute the segfault to.

Comment: @nitzanms Ah yeah, that's a good point. I'd say you can use the same `sigwaitinfo(2)` trick in Linux.